# Note, selecting 'code' instead of './code_1.63.2-1639562499_amd64.deb'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, installation

While installing VS Code on Ubuntu, I came across this message:

```
Note, selecting 'code' instead of './code_1.63.2-1639562499_amd64.deb'
```

What does this mean?

Here is the relevant part of the terminal:

```
(base) jafar_isbarov@jafar-IdeaPad-3-15ADA05:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install ./code_1.63.2-1639562499_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'code' instead of './code_1.63.2-1639562499_amd64.deb'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  brave-keyring linux-headers-5.11.0-44-generic
  linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-44 linux-image-5.11.0-44-generic
  linux-modules-5.11.0-44-generic linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-44-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  code
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 62 not upgraded.
Need to get 81,1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 339 MB of additional disk space will be used.
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You told APT to install a package named `./code_1.63.2-1639562499_amd64.deb`, but when APT looked inside that file, APT found that the file actually contains a package named `code`, not a package named `./code_1.63.2-1639562499_amd64.deb`.

This is exactly what you would expect, since `./code_1.63.2-1639562499_amd64.deb` is a package file which contains a specific version of the `code` package.

However, since the name of the package that APT is installing is different than the package you asked APT to install, APT is dutifully informing you of that fact, so that you can assess whether or not this was what you intended to happen.